# construct a Tree of the TreeLoc of each of his nodes, in scalaz

Tags: scala, tree, functional-programming, scalaz

*TreeLoc is a zipper of a Tree*

I have an Historic of action in a game that is stored in a tree (in order to store different final state in a save). So basically i have a `TreeLoc[Action]` in my Game (to know which Node is the current final state).

So now i want my user to be able to move into this historic. So what i want is to present him a Tree of his action and when he click on a Node, i calculate and replace my historic by the TreeLoc of the same root Tree but with focus on the right Node. It would be useless to create every TreeLoc associate with each Node, so i thought it would be a good solution to find a way to transform my `Tree[Action]` (which is the current `TreeLoc[Action].toTree)` into a `Tree[(Action, () => TreeLoc[Action])].` How can i do such thing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might not be understanding correctly, so please correct me if not.

You have a Tree[Action] which you present to the user, and when the user selects a node in that tree, and you want a TreeLoc focused on the selected node?  Is that right?

Something like this?

```
val tree : Tree[Action] = // build your tree

def select(userSelected: Action) : Option[TreeLoc[Action]] = {
    tree.loc.find(_.getLabel == userSelected)
}
```

The TreeLoc returned will be focused on the node that matched, but rooted in the same tree.

Obviously the find() might not be what you want, a unique id would probably be better than an equality test.

Comment: It should work but in my case Action is a case class and i can have same case class for two Action, but with eq it should work.

Comment: Bear in mind that == is structural equality in Scala not a reference compare, and that for a case class this is generated.  Two Actions with different data won't be considered ==.